# How to search content on specific branch using Github API

Tags: github, github-api

I'm using the [Github Kohsuke API](http://github-api.kohsuke.org/) to search for content on a remote repo on Github. Currently, I'm only able to pull down content from my default *master* branch. Is there a way to pull down content on a branch besides *master*? Here's the code snippet I have, which currently only pulls from my *master* branch. Thanks for any help!

```
public class GitCompareTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        GitHub github = GitHub.connect();
        GHRepository repo = github.getRepository(repo_name);
        List<GHContent> articleContents = repo.getDirectoryContent(path);

        for (GHContent content : articleContents) {

            if (content.isDirectory()) {
                PagedIterable<GHContent> childArticleContents = content.listDirectoryContent();

                for (GHContent childArticleContent : childArticleContents) {
                    String childText = childArticleContent.getContent();
                    String.out.println(childText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `getDirectoryContent(String path, String ref)` using your branch's name for `ref`.
A branch name is essentially a name for a specific commit in git, and "ref" is git terminology for "name of a specific commit".

(Disclaimer: I haven't used Kohsuke's GitHub library yet, I'm drawing from general git knowledge.)